# Separate ID numbers in a column separated by a ,

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

I need a bit of help separating id's that are separated by a comma and then displaying them in a dropdown list.

Here's the code below that i am working with, if the clothing_type_id has only 1 number in it, it works fine, if i add more numbers so it's split by a comma i.e  1,2,3,4 it will no longer work, i'm sure i need to use explode but i can not get it to work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<? $clothing=intval($_GET['clothing_var']);
include 'classes.php';
mysql_select_db('database');
$query="SELECT ID,Qty_Values FROM Quantity WHERE Clothing_Type_ID='$clothing'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$test=explode(',', '$result');

?>
<select name="state" onchange="getCity(<?=$clothing?>,this.value)">
<option>Select State</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($test)) { ?>
<option value=<?=$row['ID']?>><?=$row['Qty_Values']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

UPDATE:

Here's what i'm trying todo.

Hi, pasted your code in and although it works, it only brings up the first selection, if i click on the 2nd id nothing displays. My database table goes like this, the fist selection called Clothing_Type  has 3 columns, ID Garment and Price, the second table has 4 columns, ID, Clothing_Type_ID, Qty_Values and price. Basically I am trying to do is make a pricing guide so if i select a t-shirt in the first selection box it will bring up 4 prices at the end of the form, 1 for each item, 2 for a total amount (If selecting a higher quantity) 3 for VAT and 4 Total Amount. Every time selection is selected then it will automatically update the price. After i've selected 3 or 4 selection boxes, i then want a few checkboxes again to update the price if they're ticked.

Update 2: Here's the js and html

JS

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getXMLHTTP() {
    var xmlhttp=false;  
    try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)    {       
        try{            
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1){
                xmlhttp=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}

function getQty(countryId) {        

    var strURL="findQty.php?clothing_var="+countryId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById('qtydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                       
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }       
}
function getCity(countryId,stateId) {       
    var strURL="findCity.php?clothing_var="+countryId+"&qty_var="+stateId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }

}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="" name="form1">
<?
include 'classes.php';
$query="SELECT ID,Garment FROM Clothing_Type";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<select name="clothing_type" onChange="getQty(this.value)">
<option>Select Clothing Type</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value=<?=$row['ID']?>><?=$row['Garment']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>

<p id="qtydiv">
<select style="width: 150px;" name="qty" disabled='disabled'>
<option>Select Country First</option>
</select>
</p>

<p id="citydiv">
<select style="width: 150px;" name="city" disabled='disabled'>
<option>Select State First</option>
</select>

</p>

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> I want to live here<br />
<form>
<input type='checkbox' name='1' value='1'id='checkbox_1' />1<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='2' value='2'id='checkbox_2' />2<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='3' value='3'id='checkbox_3' />3<br>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to change your query to use AND - you also don't want to do it like you are not as you are open to SQL Injection attacks

Comment: Whats contained in the $clothing variable?

Comment: Hi matt, that would be the results from the first selection box, see second update as i've posted the html and js, hopefully that will give you a better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

$clothing = "1,2,3,4";

$query="SELECT ID,Qty_Values FROM Quantity WHERE Clothing_Type_ID IN ($clothing)";

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, putting in $clothing = "1,2,3,4"; ignore the results from the first selection box

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the `IN()` operator instead of just comparing to a comma-separated string:

```
$query = "SELECT ID, Qty_Values FROM Quantity WHERE Clothing_Type_ID IN($clothing)";
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, the id column has 1,2,3,4,5 but this script only brings up 1 ... anything after , does not appear

Answer (score 0):

Update your SQL to this..

```
$query="SELECT ID,Qty_Values FROM Quantity WHERE Clothing_Type_ID in ($clothing)";
```

Get rid of the explode. This will return a result set of the clothes that have a clothing type Id that is listed in your $clothing list.

Part of me thinks you are doing this backwards. I'm assuming each item in the DB only has 1 clothing type ID and the list of ids is in your $clothing string.

If this isn't the case give me an example look at your DB table.

Comment: Hi, pasted your code in and although it works, it only brings up the first selection, if i click on the 2nd id nothing displays.

Comment: I've just updated to give you a better idea of what i'm trying to do.